# Can not change brightness Ubuntu 22.04 external monitor problem

Tags: brightness, 22.04

I have problem controll brightness external monitor(hdmi) by Ubuntu software.

- ## brightness-controller ubuntu cannot run to external monitor
- ## xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --brightness 0.5  cannot run to external monitor too

Before: At Ubuntu 20.04 all running well

I use HP-240-G6-Notebook i7-7500U CPU - Intel HD Graphics 620

Comment: this is no question. We don't even know which graphics card you have. Do you expect "crystal balls"?

Comment: "external monitors" usually have brightness controls in the monitor, rather than in software on the PC.

Comment: i7-7500U CPU - Intel HD Graphics 620

Answer (score 0):

after testing all the solutions I found in StackOverflow and over the internet, I have finally found a way to fix the problem...

I don't know if it will work for you, but worth a test:

Open the nvida settings:

```
nvidia-settings
```

Check if your monitor is being run by your GPU and if so, you can click and go to the Color Correction tab, as the image below:
[image]

Adjust the Brightness & Contrast, and click to save the modifications.

I hope it works for you as worked for me.